# Compute accuracy for CNN using TensorFlow and flow_from_directory

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using flow_from_directory method to feeding data into neural network:

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('.../train', target_size=(img_width, img_height), batch_size=32,class_mode='categorical')
```

Now I want to print (calculate) the training accuracy. When you have splitted training data to y_train and x_train, you use something like this:

```
training_accuracy = compute_accuracy(y_train, model.predict(x_train))
```

But I dont have splitted data. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**flow_from directory** returns a tuple of (x, y) where x is a numpy array containing a batch of images with shape (batch_size, *target_size, channels) and y is a numpy array of corresponding labels.

So your **x_train** would be **train_generator[0]** and **y_train** is **train_generator[1]**